# Can anyone explain why this setinterval runs for 21 seconds. Math says it should run for 20

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to make a timer for my quiz app. I have a setinterval that runs every 20 ms and increments a number by 0.1 starting from 0 to 100. I have noticed however that it actually runs for 21 seconds instead of 20 while both the timer and the progress bar seemingly works fine.

Here's a minimum example of a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-8pfcdu?file=src/App.js) to showcase my problem.
I've been using multiple phone's stopwatches to check and it always runs for 21 seconds which bothers my ocd.

Can someone explain to me why it happens? It's the same if i use bigger values for the setinterval frequency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, it's hard to see *exactly* what the problem is, but you've got a few issues in the code that could be the cause.

First, you don't need to have the `timerWidth` as a state property - this is essentially *derived state* that you can calculate based on `secondsRemaining`. If we create some constants to represent the timing:

```js
const TIMEOUT_SECS = 20;
const INTERVAL_MILLIS = 50;
```

Then we can calculate the width based on how many seconds are remaining:

```js
const timerWidth = ((TIMEOUT_SECS - secondsRemaining) / TIMEOUT_SECS) * 100;
```

Now, you can simplify your `useEffect` where you create the timer - and crucially, we can add `answer` as a dependency for the effect, because you don't need to run this effect on every render. You only need to re-run the effect if `answer` changes.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (answer === null) {
    timerRef.current = setInterval(() => {
      setSecondsRemaining(prev => Math.max(0, prev - (INTERVAL_MILLIS / 1000)));
    }, INTERVAL_MILLIS);
  }

  return () => {
    clearInterval(timerRef.current);
  };
}, [answer]);
```

Notice here I'm also using the form of `setState` which modifies the state based on its previous value - this is crucial because if we change the code to this:

```
setSecondsRemaining(Math.max(secondsRemaining- (INTERVAL_MILLIS / 1000), 0));
```

We've introduced a bug - the value of `secondsRemaining` is captured when the effect runs (i.e. we've created a closure). Using this code will cause the timer to look like it only updates once.

Finally - you need to make sure you stop the timer once it reaches zero (or reset the timer, or whatever you want to do):

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (secondsRemaining <= 0) {
    clearInterval(timerRef.current);
  }
}, [secondsRemaining]);
```

[Here's a StackBlitz that puts it all together](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-tmxrga?file=src/App.js). I added some logging for starting/stopping the timer, and when I ran it I got:

```
START 2021-08-02T07:09:05.630Z
STOP 2021-08-02T07:09:25.631Z
```

One more thing to remember - using the interval to count time is super unreliable - you're not guaranteed that you'll get called at the interval you specify (it all depends on the browser). A more reliable way would be to instead store the time when the timer starts, and then work out how much it's changed each time the interval is called back.